# Input events in form from ajax request

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms

A user can click on a button and jQuery will make an ajax request to the server, which will return a form. My problem is, that the form elements like file input or checkboxes lose their default events. I can't check/uncheck the checkbox and the input won't open a file dialog anymore.

Is there any way I can reassign these events to the elements?

I'm not talking about events I wrote myself. Do the standard events have a specific name in jQuery, so I can use .on()?

Comment: Is the page actually reloading on click? You can make the button not submit by giving it the attribute `type="button"`.

Comment: No, the page doesn't reload. I have a container, where the form gets placed inside.